# ASP.NET MVC TagBuilder.SetInnerText() not setting the text correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tagbuilder

So I am creating a HtmlHelper extension method and I have run into a problem when using TagBuilder.SetInnerText().  The helper outputs an option tag.  Here is the source of the helper:

```
public static string Option(this HtmlHelper helper, string value, string text, object htmlAttributes) {
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("option");

        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", value);
        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(text);

        return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
    }
```

In my view I call

```
<%= Html.Option("value", "text", new { }) %>
```

but the inner text of the tag does not get set and I am left with

```
<option value="value"> </option>
```

Any ideas on why the SetInnerText() is not setting the text correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) - is the problem
```

It tries to output `<option value="" />`, where there is nowhere to insert InnerText.

Make it:

```
return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)
```

Comment: Omitting the render mode will also work. TagRenderMode.Normal is the [render mode used by `.ToString()`](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#266517).

Answer (score -1):

I think that correct way to use `InnerText` is this below. You need to set `InnerText` on Create Tag, and after you define extra attributes.

```
TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("select")
{
    InnerHtml = "set Anything"
};
tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", value);
```